# CKEditor 4 удаляет iframe

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

Есть проблема. `CKEditor 4` удаляет тег `iframe` когда вставляю видео с Youtube. Предложенные гуглом способы не работают. Подскажите, что можно сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ещё актуально — добавьте код из файла подключения.

У Вас могут быть запрещены `iframe` через `invalid_elements`.

Также можно попробовать внести в перечень принудительно разрешённых, прописав в 
коде: `extended_valid_elements: iframe[*]`.